# Obtaining scroll position on mobile phone/device

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll

I want to make a mobile device to scroll to a certain position and then output it as an alert. My code works fine in chrome on my PC but not on mobile devices. When I run developer tools in chrome on my PC and select view on mobile devices it doesn't work, even though it works fine in the PC view mode. If I set the position to say 30 pixels the screen doesn't move at all, in mobile device view, and the alert comes back with zero. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="crafty/crafty_postcode.class.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cc-cdn.com/generic/scripts/v1/cc_c2a.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body id="mainBodyId" style="margin-left:0.25cm;height: 1500px;width:1200px;"  >'

<script  language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
window.scrollTo(0,30);
alert('Current scroll from the top: ' + window.pageYOffset);
</script>

<form>
<span>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4
    <br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7
    <button>test</button>
    <br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>
    <button>test</button>
    1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>
    5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>
    8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>
    2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>
    <button>test</button>
    <br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3
    <br>4<br>5<br>
    <button>test</button>
    6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>
    9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>
    3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6
    <br>7<br>8<br>9
    <button>test</button>
    <br>10<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>1<br>2<br>
    3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>6<br>7<br>8<br>9<br>10<br>
    <button>test</button>
</span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the screen to move to 30 pixels vertically and the alert to output 30 while in chrome developer tools, mobile device view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out instead of `window.scrollTo(0, 30)`

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   window.scrollTo(0,30);
});
```

Comment: Your suggestion works in the desktop view mode(in developer tools) but not when I toggle to view it in the mobile device mode.

Comment: Hey @JamesCurrie I've updated the code and it works on mobile device as well. 
I'm not sure why it is not working with chorme mobile view, but I tested it on actual mobile device and it sure works.